# How can I change _XTRAS_LIST and keep it from being overridden?

Tags: aegir

I'm running BOA on Linode Server and here is the last line of my barracuda_log.txt file:

```
Sun Jun 22 10:39:16 EDT 2014 / Ubuntu.lucid x86_64 XEN / Aegir BOA-2.2.6 / Barracuda BOA-2.2.6 / Nginx 1.7.2 / PHP 5.3 5.2 / FPM 5.3 / CLI 5.3 / MariaDB-5.5.38 FQDN / Wildcard NO
```

I want to add the Compass Tools and FFmpeg support, so in my .barracuda.cnf I changed `_XTRAS_LIST="CSF CHV FTP"` 
to

```
_XTRAS_LIST="CSF CHV FTP CSS FMG"
```

However, upon running barracuda up-stable it returns to

```
_XTRAS_LIST="CSF CHV FTP"
```

I tried adding `_EASY_PUBLIC=NO` to the end of the .barracuda.cnf, but that didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

It is a [known bug](https://github.com/omega8cc/boa/issues/319) affecting Ubuntu instances.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't find that when I was searching for answers.